# According to Facebook - How to properly embed a Facebook hosted video on your website

Tags: html, css, facebook, video, embed

I am attempting to embed a video from Facebook into my website. According to FB, the following code is how to accomplish this, simply replacing the URL of their sample video with the URL of my video. I tested this code on its own and as part of my website with the URL replaced. The results are the same, nothing loads, and the div containing the "video" appears to be collapsed when inspecting the code in the browser. Does anyone have some insight as to why that is? Link to the source is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player#configeration

```html
<html>
  <title>My Website</title>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
  <h1>My Video Player</h1>
  <div class="fb-video"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553"
    data-width="500"
    data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried more than one video to see if a diff link works? Make this -- "According to FB" -- a link to the source, plz.

Comment: I actually took the video link out of the URL and tested it alone, it works fine. So does the video link I want to put in there. The content is valid, the method of displaying it in my website seems to be the problem.

Comment: Your link has a spelling mistake.

Comment: I was just fooling around with this and found the same thing. I got nothing at all. I tried 3 different approaches. Then I tried a different browser and they all worked. Something is blocking them on my Firefox browser, but not Chrome. Edit: of course, I have this thing called Facebook Container installed. That's the blocker for me. Check your add-ons. The network tab in dev tools might tell you right away. I had the CSS button checked in dev tools so wasn't seeing everything right away, watch out for that.

Comment: My issue seems to have been the <DOCTYPE> section, I apparently had copied a header from a code section when I started the document which had some sort of modifier that causes Chrome to see it as HTML 4 and toggle Quirks mode. When I replaced that with the standard formart for HTML 5, it worked. Good tip though!